# What is a good way to encode diffs in absence of the source text?

Tags: diff, text-processing

The situation is this like: there's some text

```
hello world!
```

It is processed by my tool and is converted to some symbolic form, e.g.

```
[hello@0, world@6]
```

(notice how the `!` is discarded).

Now my tool wants to recommend adding `there` to the original source text. My tool can send textual data back, so it makes sense to encode the delta in some format and send it back. Here's an example with [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff):

```
1c1
< hello world!
---
> hello there world!
```

But the problem is that I cannot use the classical diff format because I don't have the original text any longer, and I can't produce that text from my model accurately (for example, because the `!` is missing).

My question is, is there some standard textual format that can encode modifications in the middle of the line without knowing the entire line? Something like:

```
insert 'there ' at 1:6
```

I know `diff` itself has a few other possible output formats, but I could not spot anyone which can add things to the middle of a line without needing the entire new line content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the output formats of `diff` is an `ed` script with `diff -e`. Now, `diff` produces `ed` scripts that make line-oriented edits, like delete lines or insert lines.

But since you're not necessarily using `diff`, you can make your tool output a finer-grained `ed` script which performs insertions and substitutions within a line.

Ed does not support numeric addressing of the characters within a line, but it can be done with regular expression match/replace.

To replace an n-character sequence starting at column m (counting from 1) with the text `rep`, you can use this command:

```
s/\(.\{m-1\}\).\{n\}/\1rep/
```

Here `m-1` and `n` are replaced by decimal numbers. If m happens to be 1, then just

```
s/.\{n\}/&rep/
```

Your program has be careful about escaping the characters of `rep`, of course.

The edits are then applied to a file like this:

```
$ cp file file.tmp                        # operate in-place on file.tmp
$ (cat diffs ; echo wq) | ed -q file.tmp  # edits are in file "diffs"
```